# Mysql БД не распознает кирилицу

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, кодировка

У меня к Java проекту подключена Mysql БД. При записи данных в БД с русскими буквами, они сохраняются в виде  "ÐÐ½Ð´ÑÑÐ¹". Как это можно исправить ?

Comment: добавить параметр `chararcterEncoding=UTF-8` к jdbc url http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Comment: Добавил в самом начале. Но все равно не работает
?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8

Comment: а у самой БД какая кодировка стоит?

Comment: Да. В БД кодировка стоит

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась не с БД, а с JSP страницей. Данные со страницы поступают не в той кодировке в которой нужно.